# Data-wrangling large list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, case, purrr

I have a large list of data frames which have identical column names. I would like to write code that applies the same rules for data wrangling to each of the data frames contained within the list. An example of the list output from the R global environment [A list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0sj0.png) To provide an example of the data frames contained within the list, I have created two example data frames with runnable code here:

```
df<-data.frame(Event.Type = c("SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6","SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5","SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA",  "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5","SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER3", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5","SEVT_USER5","SEVT_USER5"),
               (Event.Label = c(NA, "Auto Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", NA, "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", NA, "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger","AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Double Trigger", NA, "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", NA, "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Double Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", NA, "AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "High Leak", "AASM", "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", NA, "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger",  "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", NA, "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Ineffective Effort", "AASM", "Ineffective Effort", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM",  "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "High Leak", "Double Trigger", NA, "AASM", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", "AASM", "High Leak", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "High Leak", "Auto Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Hyperventilation", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger","Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger"))) 

df2<- data.frame(Event.Type = c("SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6",                "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6",  "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5","SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5"),
                 Event.Label = c("Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Ineffective Effort", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "High Leak", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger",  NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger",  NA, "Auto Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA,  "Auto Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger",  "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger",  "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger",  "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", NA, NA, "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Auto Trigger", NA, "High Leak", "Ineffective Effort", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "High Leak", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, NA, "Hypoventilation", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", NA, "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", NA,  NA, "Auto Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", NA, "Hypoventilation", NA, NA, "Double Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Auto Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", NA, "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger" )) 

A_list<- list(df, df2)
```

An example of the intended data wrangling for an individual data frame (df2) :

```
df3<- df2 %>% mutate(Event.Type =
                 case_when(Event.Type == "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA" ~ "hypopnea",
                           Event.Type == "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA" ~ "obstruct_apnea",
                           Event.Type == "SEVT_MIXED_APNEA" ~ "mixed_apnea",
                           Event.Type == "SEVT_CENTRAL_APNEA" ~ "central_apnea")) %>% 
  mutate(Event.Label=
           case_when(Event.Label == "Auto Trigger" ~ "auto_trig",
                     Event.Label == "Double Trigger" ~ "double_trig",
                     Event.Label == "Ineffective Effort" ~ "ineffective_eff",
                     Event.Label == "High Leak" ~ "high_leak",
                     Event.Label == "Hyperventilation" ~ "hyperventilation",
                     Event.Label == "Hypoventilation" ~ "hypoventilation")) %>% 
  mutate(Events = coalesce(Event.Type, Event.Label))
  
df4<- df3[!(is.na(df3$Events)), ]
```

Reading the online resources, I assume writing code that includes purr:map is the most efficient way to do this; however, I can't seem to find any examples that use dplyr::mutate or dplyr::case_when function. Am I correct in thinking this is an efficient way to tackle the task to hand? If so, any input as to how to write the code to apply data wrangling to a large list of data frames is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One solution is to create a function i.e. `wrangling <- function(df) { ... }` where ... is the dplyr code you posted, then do `A_list_wrangled <- purrr::map(A_list, wrangling)`

Comment: Thanks Ric.  In terms of the function component, how do I make the data frame code generic rather than df2, df3 etc. ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're wanting something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

map(A_list, ~ mutate(., Event.Type = case_when(
                          Event.Type == "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA" ~ "hypopnea",
                          Event.Type == "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA" ~ "obstruct_apnea",
                          Event.Type == "SEVT_MIXED_APNEA" ~ "mixed_apnea",
                          Event.Type == "SEVT_CENTRAL_APNEA" ~ "central_apnea"),
                        Event.Label = case_when(Event.Label == "Auto Trigger" ~ "auto_trig",
                          Event.Label == "Double Trigger" ~ "double_trig",
                          Event.Label == "Ineffective Effort" ~ "ineffective_eff",
                          Event.Label == "High Leak" ~ "high_leak",
                          Event.Label == "Hyperventilation" ~ "hyperventilation",
                          Event.Label == "Hypoventilation" ~ "hypoventilation"),
                          Events = coalesce(Event.Type, Event.Label)) %>% 
              filter(!is.na(Events)))
```

Or to do as [Ric suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76751149/data-wrangling-large-list-of-dataframes-in-r/76751302#comment135310610_76751149):

```
process_df <- function(df) {
  mutate(df, Event.Type = case_when(
                          Event.Type == "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA" ~ "hypopnea",
                          Event.Type == "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA" ~ "obstruct_apnea",
                          Event.Type == "SEVT_MIXED_APNEA" ~ "mixed_apnea",
                          Event.Type == "SEVT_CENTRAL_APNEA" ~ "central_apnea"),
                        Event.Label = case_when(Event.Label == "Auto Trigger" ~ "auto_trig",
                          Event.Label == "Double Trigger" ~ "double_trig",
                          Event.Label == "Ineffective Effort" ~ "ineffective_eff",
                          Event.Label == "High Leak" ~ "high_leak",
                          Event.Label == "Hyperventilation" ~ "hyperventilation",
                          Event.Label == "Hypoventilation" ~ "hypoventilation"),
                          Events = coalesce(Event.Type, Event.Label)) %>% 
              filter(!is.na(Events))
}

map(A_list, process_df)
```

In map, you can either pass a function like the example just above, or pass it as an anonymous function (as in the first example). There are a few different ways of formatting anonymous functions in R, the one I used is just one.

The main alternative to the `map` functions are the `apply` functions (`sapply`, `lapply` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `dplyr::rowwise()` instead of `purrr::map()`. For this kind of operation its good to have the data in a nested `data.frame`. Below I create this nested `data.frame` with `dplyr::nest_by()`. Note that this automatically applies `rowwise()` so there is no need to use it directly.

```r
library(dplyr)

nested_dfs <- df |> 
  bind_rows(df2, .id = "id") |> 
  nest_by(id)

nested_dfs |>  # nest_by() automatically applies `dplyr::rowwise()`
  mutate(data = list(
    
    data |> 
      mutate(
        Event.Type =
          case_when(Event.Type == "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA" ~ "hypopnea",
                    Event.Type == "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA" ~ "obstruct_apnea",
                    Event.Type == "SEVT_MIXED_APNEA" ~ "mixed_apnea",
                    Event.Type == "SEVT_CENTRAL_APNEA" ~ "central_apnea"),
        Event.Label=
          case_when(Event.Label == "Auto Trigger" ~ "auto_trig",
                    Event.Label == "Double Trigger" ~ "double_trig",
                    Event.Label == "Ineffective Effort" ~ "ineffective_eff",
                    Event.Label == "High Leak" ~ "high_leak",
                    Event.Label == "Hyperventilation" ~ "hyperventilation",
                    Event.Label == "Hypoventilation" ~ "hypoventilation"),
        
        Events = coalesce(Event.Type, Event.Label)
        ) |>  # close inner mutate
      filter(!is.na(Events))
  ) # close list
  ) # close outer mutate

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Rowwise:  id
#>   id    data              
#>   <chr> <list>            
#> 1 1     <tibble [13 x 4]> 
#> 2 2     <tibble [196 x 4]>
```

Data from OP

```r
df<-data.frame(Event.Type = c("SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6","SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5","SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA",  "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5","SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_TYPE3_AROUSAL", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER3", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5","SEVT_USER5","SEVT_USER5"),
               (Event.Label = c(NA, "Auto Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", NA, "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", NA, "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger","AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Double Trigger", NA, "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", NA, "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Double Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", NA, "AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "High Leak", "AASM", "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", NA, "AASM", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger",  "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", NA, "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Ineffective Effort", "AASM", "Ineffective Effort", "AASM", "AASM", "AASM",  "Double Trigger", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "High Leak", "Double Trigger", NA, "AASM", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", "AASM", "High Leak", "Double Trigger", "AASM", "High Leak", "Auto Trigger", "AASM", "AASM", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Hyperventilation", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger","Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger"))) 

df2<- data.frame(Event.Type = c("SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER1", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6",                "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER6",  "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_SPO2_DESAT", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_APNEA", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_OBSTRUCTIVE_HYPOPNEA", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5","SEVT_USER4", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER5", "SEVT_USER2", "SEVT_USER6", "SEVT_USER5"),
                 Event.Label = c("Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Ineffective Effort", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "High Leak", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger",  NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger",  NA, "Auto Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA,  "Auto Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger",  "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger",  "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger",  "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", NA, NA, "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Auto Trigger", NA, "High Leak", "Ineffective Effort", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "High Leak", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", NA, "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", NA, NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", NA, NA, NA, "Hypoventilation", NA, "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", NA, "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", NA,  NA, "Auto Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", NA, "Auto Trigger", NA, "Hypoventilation", NA, NA, "Double Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Auto Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", NA, "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", "Auto Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", "Ineffective Effort", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Hypoventilation", "Double Trigger", "Hypoventilation", "Auto Trigger", "Double Trigger" ))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Tim- this looks like a helpful solution for some of my other data wrangling!